# Move using keyboard instead of drag and drop

Tags: finder, macos, folders, copy-paste, file-transfer

I wonder how I can move items/folders using keyboard instead of drag and drop. Like sometimes I'm opening a folder and there is an item in it which I want to move it to another location but I don't want to open another finder window and drag and drop.
I'm using macOS Sierra

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add what version of macOS you're using? Different versions can use different/additional keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @Monomeeth I'm using Sierra and updated the question

Comment: @Monomeeth so apparently I need an external software to do that?

Comment: I can't speak from personal experience as it's not something I've ever needed to do via the keyboard. I was just flagging the other question in case it contained answers for you. Maybe someone else will come up with a different solution.

Comment: @Monomeeth so what do you do to move items? Open two finder windows and drag and drop?

Comment: I don't find I have to move files around too often, but generally I use the Columns view and will have multiple tabs of that within the same Finder window. You can drag and drop from one tab to another, all within the same _window_. I suppose if I found myself regularly moving files to a particular location I could create a service (maybe with a keyboard shortcut) to perform the action, but I rarely have to move files around so haven't needed to worry about it.

Comment: By the way, I notice that you can also use [LaunchBar](https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) for free, so maybe you should investigate that as a possible solution for you.

Comment: @Monomeeth but LaunchBar is trial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Cut, Copy or Paste using the keyboard - though as Finder has no actual Cut command, you move files in a slightly different way from how you would do it on Windows.

Copy is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd> 
Paste is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd> 
very similar to Windows, however, cutting a file leaves the potential for losing it, if for instance you forgot, or had a power cut, or copied something else before you remembered to paste, etc.

So Finder doesn't let you do that.
Instead it leaves the file exactly where it was until you make the actual call to move it.
You do that with Copy, as above, then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd> .
Think of it as 'Option Paste'.

That will securely move the file to its new location. That can be on the same volume, or a different one. It will execute the move differently for each of those scenarios, but the end result is the same, your file is now safely in its new location.

Amongst the methods for picking where it will go...

- Open two Finder windows, so you can see source & destination simultaneously.
- Use column view, which you can navigate using just the arrow keys.
- Use Tab view, so you can have two or more locations ready in a single window.

Answer (score -2):

You can use "Cut" then "Paste"

Comment: Cut? I'm using macOS

Comment: Sorry, it's Copy and Paste

Comment: But I don't want to copy, I want to move which is the equivalent to Cut in windows

Comment: Hi @Mandy welcome to Ask Different and thank you for posting your answer. However, your answer as it currently reads, doesn't actually address the OP's question. For example, they're after a solution using a keyboard and your answer doesn't clarify how they would do this? Perhaps you could take the time to revisit your response?

Comment: @Tak Command+Option+V will move the item to wherever you want it to go.